# How to implement feign requests that support Spring pagination?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to make a feign request that returns a spring page. The method at the controller expects `Pageable pageable` parameter:

```
@GetMapping("/artists")
public Page<Artist> findArtists(Pageable pageable){
}
```

My attempt to pass the `Pageable pageable` with the feign client at the other end:

```
@FeignClient("artists-service")
public interface ArtistsFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/artists")
    Page<Artist> finadArtists(Pageable pageable);
}
```

did not work.
How should i write the feign client so I can make a request that returns a page.

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/556), hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pageable are not supported by Spring Cloud Feign client as https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/26. You can use RestTempate.